# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs at boot after running `nvidia-xconfig`

Tags: boot, nvidia

Ubuntu 18.04.4 stuck at the loading screen after running the following command and rebooting:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

I forcefully shut it down a couple of times and when I started it again it still hangs there.

[image]

I'm standing here looking at the screen and I can't believe that NVIDIA is a 230 bln $ company.

What solutions are there?
Is there any way I could access the terminal from here in order to delete the `xorg.conf` file?

If I press `ctrl+alt+F4`, it takes me to a screen which says:

```
xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishers up
```

Comment: **Nvidia-xconfig** should have created a backup of your former **xorg.conf** .So login in on one of the TTYs via your username and password , then run ```cd /etc/X11/ ;sudo mv xorg.conf xorg.conf.nv ;sudo mv xorg.conf.backup xorg.conf```then reboot.Note that this only would work if the former **xorg.conf** had worked for you.I've never seen the config made by Nvidia for X11 works correctly.I don't know why.

Comment: A windowsy company, no wonder Apple ditched them. Last time I buy a computer with NVIDIA. I think AMD is just about as good now. Looking forward to other GPU manufacturers entering the market.

I have written below what worked for me. I still have a question there. Isn't that wrong that I wasn't required to enter a password in order to access root?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

At startup, press `Esc`. Right after the logo disappears press once, don't press it too many times to get to `grub`.

In the next window I had 3 options:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System setup
```

Choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.
Next, select:

1. `Ubuntu with Linux *version* (recovery mode)`
2. `root`
3. `OK`.

Press `Enter` once and type:

```
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
reboot
```

Worked fine. But now I have another question: I was not required to enter my root password, anyone could have altered my system. What can I do to protect root access?

Comment: In terminal run ```sudo su``` then  ```passwd``` and then assign a password to your root account if you haven't already done that.

Comment: I think that simply changes my `sudo` password. I already had a `sudo` password, and yet I wasn't asked for any password in order to access `root`.

Comment: No that changes the **root** password , not the password you have to enter when you run **sudo**.That password I mentioned is for when you want to **LOGIN** as root(i.e when you type **root** as the user). And also linux has a caching mechanism (I don't know which subsystem exactly) that caches your entered credentials so that in a **process** like bash when you enter your password , you don't require to enter it for running any program as root for as long as I think 10 minutes.

Comment: And also if you access the root user via ```sudo su``` because you're a **sudoer** user , you have to enter **your own** password , not the root's. But when you run **su** or when you want to login as root , you have to enter the **root** password not your own.

Comment: I have just checked and it changes my sudo password. After running that command I get `Password:`. No matter what I input, I get: 
`su: Authentication failure /
Changing password for admin. /
(current) UNIX password:
`

Comment: I'm confused . You did ```su``` then ```passwd``` or ```sudo su``` then ```passwd``` ? in the first case you haven't yet assigned any password to root so you cannot change the user to root.You get ```su: Authentication failure``` because you have entered the wrong password for **root**.You have to use the second one first since you haven't setup the root password : ```sudo su``` then ```passwd```.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!!
Note: one might want to change the `keyring` password too.