# `nvidia-xconfig` breaks boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I would like to test some GPU overclocking add fan speed settings on my machine.

For that I need to enable the `Coolbits` option in the `Device` section ([Enabling overclocking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Enabling_overclocking)):

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=12
```

It seems that this line above will create a `xorg.conf` file, but the
`Coolbits` option does is not written under `Device`, but under `Screen` configurations.

Even so, if I only create the `xorg.conf` file with `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, and then manually add
`Option   "Coolbits" "12"` in the "Device" Section to make it look like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "Coolbits" "12"
EndSection
```

when I restart the machine, Ubuntu 18.04.4 does not get past the loading screen:
[Ubuntu 18.04 hangs at boot after running `nvidia-xconfig`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252079/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-at-boot-after-running-nvidia-xconfig)

Others encountered the same problem:

- [Running "nvidia-xconfig" breaks boot... how can I fix this?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cm3ocr/running_nvidiaxconfig_breaks_boot_how_can_i_fix/)
- [Won't boot anymore after nvidia-xconfig](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193398)

I couldn't find a clear solution. How can I make the `nvidia-xconfig` work properly?

Comment: Can you boot with that **xorg.conf** if you run ```sudo depmod``` then reboot ?

Comment: I suspected the driver dependencies , so I thought it might solve the problem.In fact I suspected the line ```Driver         "nvidia"``` in the config file.Glad to see it solved :)

Comment: Actually this does not work. I forgot I was on the Intel GPU.

Comment: I've managed to solve my issue by following the instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/aqcdum/how_to_slow_laptop_dgpu_down_on_ubuntu_1810/egiye1h/). It did boot well. Also, I did run `nvidia-settings` and under **PowerMizer** I could see **Editable Performance Levels**.

Comment: So please post it as the answer and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Run :

```
sudo depmod
```

It will check all the module dependencies and updates the file `/lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/modules.dep`.